# vba Get Cube update time with formula Need to delay macro execution

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have a cube connected to Pivots in excel.
In one cell i display the "latest updated" value by this formula:

```
=CUBEVALUE("CUBE NAME";"[Measures].[Last Data Update]")
```

It takes 5-10 seconds for excel to get the time of update from the cube and update the cell. So, if i close the workbook directly after it will just say n/a when I reopen the workbook.

I have scheduled this wb to autoupdate (among other wbs) through another wb that is scheduled to run every day. 
With that I get the n/a problem.
I see two solutions which I don´t know how to get to:

1, Halt the macro for 10 seconds so it can get the date correctly.
- I have tried both Wait and Sleep Vba but this also pauses calculations.
- is there any way to only pause the macro from executing?

2, Get the update date by vba and then print it to a cell.
- I have no idea how to do this. I have searched but not found any alternative.
- Does anyone know how this could be made possible?

Thanks
Elias

SOLVED:

Just want to share my solution. Found the CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone Method which handles OLAP data sources:

```
                    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

                    Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
                        DoEvents
                    Loop
```

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821008.aspx

Comment: Did you try adding `DoEvents`? Or even `Saving` the file before closing? If the calculation is set to automatic then the cells will calculate.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the full story. Yes, I have tried both DoEvents and Saving. I also have tried Calculate but it still closes too quickly. Since the Cubevalue

Comment: Sorry for not giving the full story. Yes, I have tried both DoEvents and Saving. I also have tried Calculate but it still closes too quickly. It seems like Cubevalue is trying to retrieve the information after it has calculated. No matter how long wait time, calculate or doevents I put CubeValue does not calculate properly. However, I have noticed that if I put a manual breakpoint in the code then it calculates properly. So, how can I halt the macro for 10 seconds and have excel function normally in the meantime?

Comment: See the code that I posted :)

Answer (score 1):

Just want to share my solution. Found the CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone Method which handles OLAP data sources:

```
                        Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone

                        Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
                            DoEvents
                        Loop
```

More info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821008.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this Wait code that I wrote many years ago. This will wait for specified seconds and let excel calculate it's formula. Simply change `10` to whatever number you want.

```
Sub Sample()
    '
    '~~~> Rest of your code
    '
    Wait 10 '<~~ Wait for 10 secs
    '
    '~~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! That might have worked. I actually just solved it another way, code below!
                            `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
                                                        
                            Do While Application.CalculationState <> xlDone
                                DoEvents
                            Loop`